# Trouble expanding environment variables in Jenkins email

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am having trouble getting environment variables to expand inside an email using the Email Extension Plugin.

The master is located on a linux server and running on a windows slave. If I do something during a build step such as bat 'echo %Workspace%' - It expands fine and echos with no problem.

Inside the mail step I have something like:

```
mail(subject: 'Jenkins Build', body: 'Jenkins build $BUILD_TAG ran 
successfully', to: 'myemail')
```

The email is successfully sent but it does not expand the $BUILD_TAG variable.

I tried a few other variations such as %BUILD_TAG%, ${BUILD_TAG} ${env.BUILD_TAG}

I'm wondering if this is as simple as a groovy syntax issue or if I am missing a larger concept.

(Doing this with declarative pipeline in Blue Ocean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use double quotes for your string to get variables expanded, ie:

```
mail(subject: 'Jenkins Build', body: "Jenkins build $BUILD_TAG ran successfully", to: 'myemail')
```

See [String interpolation](http://www.groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation) in the docs